# SQL While loop getting stuck in infinite loop

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I 'm trying to write a simple while loop.

```
declare @colname as varchar =''

while @colname is not null
begin
  Select @colname = col1
  FROM Table1
  WHERE col1 in ('test1','test2','test3')

  if(@colname is not null)
   begin
    exec sp('@colname')
   end

end
```

It seems that it is getting the value of the last row it finds and keeps looping.
Any suggestions on how to fix this.

**UPDATE:** I 'm calling a stored procedure for each value that is returned by the select statement. Instead of while the logic was written using cursors. So in effect trying to convert cursor to while loop.
Thanks

Comment: I think it will never be null.  @colname will contain the last value of your SELECT at the end of it.

Comment: Loops in SQL are usually not necessary; are you sure you need to be writing a loop?  And, as others have pointed out, your SELECT statement will always return a value (unless there are no values of 'test1', 'test2', or 'test3')

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this while loop? It might help us provide advice on what to correct with your logic.

Comment: Even more, the value will always be 't' in this case since you didn't specified any lenght with varchar

Comment: Could you explain why you need a loop there... If the where clause doesn't change, can't you do it with a single SQL query?

Comment: I don't think that the stored procedure will be call everytime. I think it will be call only one time, with the last value of your SELECT

Answer (score 1):

when SELECT statement returns no rows then assignment of variable (@colname=colname) is not executed - and value of @colname remains unchanged - non-null, value from previous iteration - loop will continue forever

you need set @colname to null just before select statement - or check @@rowcount right after select statement to check if rows really were found - and if not - exit the loop

Answer (score 0):

I do not undestand your script, but maybe this will be useful:

```
declare @colname as varchar =''

while NULLIF(@colname,'') is not null
begin
  Select @colname = col1
  FROM Table1
  WHERE col1 in ('test1','test2','test3')
end
```

Your problem is on the "While condition", because '' <> NULL. Maybe you can this too:

```
while isnull(@colname,'') <> ''
```

or

```
while coalesce(@colname,'') <> ''
```

Anyway I suppose that your query is a little more complex for use this **WHILE** it this way.

Answer (score 0):

But if you really need do to this kind of stuff, if you want get out of the loop, try this :

```
declare @colname as varchar =''

while @colname is not null
begin
Select @colname = col1
FROM Table1
WHERE col1 in ('test1','test2','test3')
Select @colname = null
end
```

EDIT :

@rs almost had it.

Try this :

```
declare @t table (colname varchar(10))
insert into @t
select distinct col1
FROM Table1
WHERE col1 in ('test1','test2','test3')

declare @colname as varchar(10) =''
while @colname is not null
begin
  -- get one row from table variable
  Select top 1 @colname = colname
  FROM @t

  --execute stored procedure
  exec sp('@colname')

  --delete row from table variable so that you don't read it again
  delete from @t where colname = @colname
  --set @colname to null if there is no more value to process
if ((select count(*) from @t) = 0)
begin
select @colname = null
end
end
```

Comment: @rs Not true. Select colname = null will set the colname value to null and this will stop the loop.

Comment: yes thats true, but it will not execute SP for all the values found but only one.

Comment: @rs I know...the SP was not there when I answered first...and I exactly commented the same thing when the OP edited his question

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
declare @t table (colname varchar(10))
insert into @t
select distinct col1
FROM Table1
WHERE col1 in ('test1','test2','test3')

declare @colname as varchar =''
declare @cnt int = 0;

--set count used in loop condition
select @cnt = count(*) from @t

while @cnt > 0
begin
  -- get one row from table variable
  Select top 1 @colname = colname
  FROM @t

  --execute stored procedure
  if(@colname is not null)
   begin
    exec sp('@colname')
   end

  --delete row from table variable so that you don't read it again
  delete from @t where colname = @colname

  select @cnt = count(*) from @t
end
```

Comment: Almost this... but colname stick with his last value and the loop still infinite

Comment: @FabienTheSolution, that's true, i updated my code to handle last value

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are trying to execute a series of stored procedures. These procedures are stored in table1.col1. I would do something like the following:

```
DECLARE @ColName VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @ColName = ''

SELECT @ColName = col1
FROM Table1
WHERE Col1 > @ColName
ORDER BY Col1

While @Colname IS NOT NULL
BEGIN 
EXEC SP(@colname)

SELECT @ColName = col1
FROM Table1
WHERE col1 > @ColName
AND col1 in ('test1', 'test2', 'test3')
ORDER BY col1

END
```

Comment: i think you need top 1 on your first select or else it will be set to last value lets say test9, this will cause your while loop select to not return any rows